# Display file menu in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2019

I hide the menu bar (Main Menu) in my PhpStorm 2019.3.1. I want to display it now but I don't know how to do that. Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: If you want to keep it hidden .. but still be able to access it, assign shortcut to another "Main Menu" action -- when invoked it will be displayed as a popup menu (so it's hidden and still accessible when needed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and enter "main menu". Now you can display the main menu again.

[image]